# freeDiameter based server cannot read received buffer

Tags: c++, sockets, segmentation-fault, free-diameter

I have tried to set up a server with a specific IP address and Port number by **freeDiameter** libraries. In other side, there is a client that sends a string message via freeDiameter libraries successfully; I checked it out in Wireshark.

So, here is the problem; when I start listening from the server side, it has no problem until a client sends a connection request; if you look at the below code, **"fd_cnx_serv_accept(listener)"** is listening to a socket named **"listener"** which is bind to a specific IP address and Port number.

```
uint8_t * rcv_buf;
size_t    rcv_size;
struct cnxctx * listener_side = NULL;
int ret;



listener_side = fd_cnx_serv_accept(listener);
ret = fd_cnx_start_clear(listener_side, 0);
if(ret != 0){
    std::cout<<side<<" is unable to accept connections."<<std::endl;
    return -1;
}


ret = fd_cnx_receive(listener_side, NULL, &rcv_buf, &rcv_size);
if(ret == 0){
    std::cout<<"Message received."<<std::endl;
    listener_side = NULL;
    free(rcv_buf);
}
```

The program works fine until it gets a client request; when **"fd_cnx_serv_accept"** accept the client side, the program tries to receive the message by **"fd_cnx_receive"**; but the program stops and shows the error **"Segmentation fault (core dumped)"**. Then, I test the program by **gdb** and it shows that it is something wrong with the line 309 of **"hook.c"**. Here is the image of the error which is shown by **gdb**.

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80vlD.png)

*transcript*

```
multi-thre Thread 0x7fffff72a77 In: fd_hook_call 
[New Thread 0x7fffff72a7700 (LWP 1612914)
Thread 2 "server" received signal SIGSEGEV, Segmentation Fault
[Switching to Thread 0x7fffff72a7700 (LWP 1612914)
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging --c

0x00007ffff7f2cefc in fd_hook_call (type=HOOD_DATA_RECEIVED, msg=0x0, peer=0x0, other=0x7ffff72a6be0, pmdl=0x7ffff0000ba8 at /root/projects/start_cnx_free/third-party/libfdcore/hooks.c:309
```

It is good to mention that I am trying to write a c++ program.
How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem myself. I forgot to use fd_hooks_init() at the begining of my program to initialize necessary libraries and objects.
Here is the modified code:

```
 /* Initialize the library -- must come first since it initializes the debug facility */
int ret = fd_libproto_init();
if (ret != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to initialize libfdproto: %s\n", strerror(ret));
    return ret;
}
ret = fd_hooks_init();
if(ret != 0){
     std::cout<<"Unable to initialize the hooks."<<std::endl;
     return ret;
}
/* Initialize the config with default values */
memset(&g_conf, 0, sizeof(struct fd_config));
fd_g_config = &g_conf;
ret = fd_conf_init();
if (ret != 0) {
    printf("Unable to initialize the config with default values.");
    return ret;
}

/* Add definitions of the base protocol */
ret = fd_dict_base_protocol(fd_g_config->cnf_dict);
if (ret != 0) {
    printf("Unable to add definitions of the base protocol.");
    return ret;
}
```